# Nested While Statement not working

Tags: c#, console

I have a console program that draws a shape based on length and breadth entered by the user. When this is done. I want to ask the user if he wants to draw another shape and if yes. It should restart the program. Also, when the user is asked to enter Y for Yes or N for No. I want to ensure that the user cannot outside these two letters. I am currently using this in my main method.

```
DrawShape mn = new DrawShape();
mn.ans = "y";
while (mn.ans.ToLower() == "y")
{
    try
    {
        mn.Lenght();
        Console.WriteLine();
        mn.Breadth();
        Console.WriteLine();
        mn.Draw();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        mn.Remark();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nDO YOU WANT TO REDRAW A SHAPE? \nPRESS Y - YES or N - NO");
        mn.ans = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        while (mn.ans.ToLower() != "y" || mn.ans.ToLower() != "n")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPLEASE PRESS Y - YES or N - NO");
            mn.ans = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work as this is the output i get

[image: output]

This shows that whatever i input, the error message is still shown.

Please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How is this related to Windows Media Player?

Comment: @luiscubal Sorry it was a mistake. i forgot to clear the tags in my last question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the wrong operator, use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
while (mn.ans.ToLower() != "y" && mn.ans.ToLower() != "n") {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPLEASE PRESS Y - YES or N - NO");
        mn.ans = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or this:

```
while (!(mn.ans.ToLower() == "y" || mn.ans.ToLower() == "n")) {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPLEASE PRESS Y - YES or N - NO");
        mn.ans = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**NOTE**: You should store `mn.ans.ToLower()` to a variable to avoid duplicated code.
You can also try using `Equals` method which supports comparing string case-insensitively via the `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` passed in.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid me must have overlooked that